# Jackson JSON View - exclude view variables from the output (Spring MBV)

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jackson

So I am learning Spring MVC framework and have set up Content Negotiation using the MappingJackson2JsonView class, such that when I go to /products, I get the normal HTML view and when I go to /producs.json, I get a JSON of the model - this works great.
My question is, how do I exclude variables from the JSON output? These variables I wish to exclude are set by an Interceptor I've created to add attributes to the model that I display to HTML users;

Interceptor:

```
public class GlobalVariablesInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
    if (modelAndView != null) {
        ModelMap model = modelAndView.getModelMap();
        model.addAttribute("cp", request.getServletContext().getContextPath());

        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (!(auth instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken)) {
            Set<String> roles = auth.getAuthorities().stream().map(r -> r.getAuthority()).collect(Collectors.toSet());
            String userRoles = String.join(",", roles);
            model.addAttribute("roles", userRoles);
            model.addAttribute("authUsername", auth.getName());
        }

    }
}
}
```

JSON Bean:

```
@Bean
public MappingJackson2JsonView jsonView() {
    MappingJackson2JsonView jsonView = new MappingJackson2JsonView();
    jsonView.setPrettyPrint(true);
    return jsonView;
}

@Bean
public ViewResolver contentNegotiatingViewResolver(ContentNegotiationManager manager) {
    ContentNegotiatingViewResolver resolver = new ContentNegotiatingViewResolver();
    resolver.setContentNegotiationManager(manager);
    ArrayList<View> views = new ArrayList<>();
    views.add(jsonView());
    views.add(xmlView());
    resolver.setDefaultViews(views);
    return resolver;
}
```

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So, for the benefit of anyone who reads this in the future....

things I tried:

- Setting an explicit list of model variables to go
  forward, did this in the bean definition in the WebContextConfig.
  Didn't work.
- Querying the ModelAndView object in the postHandle
  method of the interceptor; attempting to see if the View was an
  instanceof MappingJackson2JsonView; didn't work.
- Querying the HttpServletResponse object of the postHandle method to get its
  content type and see if it was application/json (didn't work... null
  pointer exception) etc.

The one thing that did work (but is clearly not very 'resilient' code).... query the HttpServletRequest object of the postHandle method, see if the requested URL contains .json (which is the trigger for the JSON view)... if yes, then don't add these extra variables to the model in the first place:

```
public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
    if (modelAndView != null) {
        String url = request.getRequestURI().toLowerCase();
        if (!(url.contains(".json") || url.contains(".xml"))) {
            ModelMap model = modelAndView.getModelMap();
            model.addAttribute("cp", request.getServletContext().getContextPath());

            Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
            if (!(auth instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken)) {
                Set<String> roles = auth.getAuthorities().stream().map(r -> r.getAuthority()).collect(Collectors.toSet());
                String userRoles = String.join(",", roles);
                model.addAttribute("roles", userRoles);
                model.addAttribute("authUsername", auth.getName());
            }

        }
    }

}
```